# CIContext createCGImage:fromRect: stuck on semaphore when using CPU

Tags: objective-c, swift, opencl, core-image

```
    let context = CIContext(options:[kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer:true])
    let inputImage = CIImage(CGImage: image.CGImage)
    let filter = CIFilter(name:"CIGaussianBlur")
    filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let result = filter .valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as CIImage
    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(result, fromRect: inputImage.extent())
    let returnImage = UIImage(CIImage: result, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale, orientation: .Up)
    return returnImage!
```

The code works properly when using GPU, which means with a nil options to create CIContext.But when using CPU, the code stucks [image]on -[CIContext createCGImage:fromRect:]
The stack is as below.It seems sdk tried to use OpenCL to compute but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Here, at least, is a workaround: On iOS 8 and later you should no longer need to specify kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer.

Comment: I decide to change to use Accelerate framework to do burring. I use it to blur the snapshot when going background. Applying for gpu resource when going background will lead to crash sometimes as Apple limits gpu when not foreground. Thanks, anyway.